# dpkg crashing while trying to install a package

Tags: apt, dpkg

While attempting to install a package via apt-get the following.
The first error I get is:

```
    E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

And, if I run that command the box spins out of control and I get the following in /var/log/syslog

```
Aug 29 20:21:08 ip-10-202-191-4 kernel: [20571563.398546] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Aug 29 20:21:08 ip-10-202-191-4 kernel: [20571563.398552] WARNING: at /build/buildd/linux-3.0.0/arch/x86/xen/multicalls.c:182 xen_mc_flush+01c0()
Aug 29 20:21:08 ip-10-202-191-4 kernel: [20571563.398561] Modules linked in: acpiphp
Aug 29 20:21:08 ip-10-202-191-4 kernel: [20571563.398568] Pid: 31063, comm: java Tainted: G      D W   3.0.0-14-virtual #23-Ubuntu
Aug 29 20:21:08 ip-10-202-191-4 kernel: [20571563.398576] Call Trace:
Aug 29 20:21:08 ip-10-202-191-4 kernel: [20571563.398580]  [<c0648265>] ? printk+0x2d/0x2f
Aug 29 20:21:08 ip-10-202-191-4 kernel: [20571563.398586]  [<c0150462>] warn_slowpath_common+0x72/0xa0
Aug 29 20:21:08 ip-10-202-191-4 kernel: [20571563.398593]  [<c0104883>] ? xen_mc_flush+0x1b3/0x1c0
Aug 29 20:21:08 ip-10-202-191-4 kernel: [20571563.398599]  [<c0104883>] ? xen_mc_flush+0x1b3/0x1c0
Aug 29 20:21:08 ip-10-202-191-4 kernel: [20571563.398605]  [<c01504b2>] warn_slowpath_null+0x22/0x30
Aug 29 20:21:08 ip-10-202-191-4 kernel: [20571563.398611]  [<c0104883>] xen_mc_flush+0x1b3/0x1c0
Aug 29 20:21:08 ip-10-202-191-4 kernel: [20571563.398617]  [<c0104e7a>] ? xen_extend_mmu_update+0x4a/0x70
Aug 29 20:21:08 ip-10-202-191-4 kernel: [20571563.398624]  [<c0106565>] xen_set_pud_hyper+0x75/0x80
Aug 29 20:21:08 ip-10-202-191-4 kernel: [20571563.398630]  [<c01065b9>] xen_set_pud+0x49/0x60
Aug 29 20:21:08 ip-10-202-191-4 kernel: [20571563.398636]  [<c0132105>] pud_populate+0x45/0x60
Aug 29 20:21:08 ip-10-202-191-4 kernel: [20571563.398642]  [<c0208a24>] __pmd_alloc+0x74/0x90
Aug 29 20:21:08 ip-10-202-191-4 kernel: [20571563.398648]  [<c0208cb7>] handle_mm_fault+0x277/0x2c0
Aug 29 20:21:08 ip-10-202-191-4 kernel: [20571563.398655]  [<c065f45b>] do_page_fault+0x15b/0x4a0
Aug 29 20:21:08 ip-10-202-191-4 kernel: [20571563.401923]  [<c020ba24>] ? remove_vma+0x44/0x60
Aug 29 20:21:08 ip-10-202-191-4 kernel: [20571563.401923]  [<c020d9b6>] ? sys_mmap_pgoff+0x106/0x1c0
Aug 29 20:21:08 ip-10-202-191-4 kernel: [20571563.401923]  [<c065f300>] ? vmalloc_fault+0x190/0x190
Aug 29 20:21:08 ip-10-202-191-4 kernel: [20571563.401923]  [<c065c79f>] error_code+0x67/0x6c
Aug 29 20:21:08 ip-10-202-191-4 kernel: [20571563.401923] ---[ end trace 0b105e2a179ad013 ]---
```

Comment: What are you trying to install?

Comment: At the moment 'rrdtool'

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the script responsible for setting up the package(either the preinst or the postinst) has a command that causes a kernel panic, or just a kernel oops. Therefore, we must clean out the bad package to keep it from trying to run through `dpkg` and cause a crash again. To to so, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below, one by one.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock 

sudo cp -arf /var/lib/dpkg /var/lib/dpkg.backup

sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status-bad

sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status

sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/available /var/lib/dpkg/available-bad

sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/available-old /var/lib/dpkg/available

sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/updates/*

sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists

sudo rm /var/cache/apt/*.bin

sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists

sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/partial

LANG=C;sudo apt-get clean

LANG=C;sudo apt-get autoclean

LANG=C;sudo apt-get --purge autoremove

LANG=C;sudo apt-get update

sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

*(The above commands are complements of ObsessiveFOSS)*

Once you do that, and all is OK, then proceed with the instructions below on how to install your package.

To install RRDTool, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.  To make sure you have all the required dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install libpango1.0-dev libxml2-dev

sudo apt-get install librrds-perl rrdtool
```

Or you can install it from the Ubuntu Software Center, by clicking below:

[image]

If the installation fails again, perform the repair steps listed above and file a bug against the package, stating that either the preinst or the postinst seems to cause a kernel panic.

Comment: Trying to install a package won't work if the package manager is broken and trying to fix it results in a kernel panic.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS The OP is getting a dpkg error, installing using the above will solve it.

Comment: The error means that there is a package that failed midway through installation, and it needs to be either fully-installed or fully removed before anything else can be done. Trying to finish the installation causes a kernel panic, which is not a way to rectify the situation. If you would like to discuss this in chat, join the main room and ping me there.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly these commands do? Are you removing some packages? This looks scary: "apt-get --purge autoremove", what does it do?

Comment: @matteo `apt-get --purge autoremove` removes packages that were installed by other packages and are no longer needed.  Other commands please see [apt-get manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/apt-get).